# Regex boolean not

Tags: .net, regex

How do I write a .net regex which will match a string that does NOT start with "Seat"

Comment: Why would you use regex rather than !stringInstance.StartsWith("Seat")

Comment: It could be part of a larger expression.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you're looking for is:

```
^(?!Seat).+
```

[This article](http://timstall.dotnetdevelopersjournal.com/regular_expressions_does_not_start_with.htm) has more information about look aheads.

Comment: Neato.  I previously had not seen this construct.  Nice!

Comment: That is quite useful, I'll have to remember that.

Comment: Mark my answer correct, I'd like the reputation points please ;)

Answer (score 7):

Writing a regex for a "does not start with" can be a little tricky.  It's often easier to write a regex to detect that a string starts with a substring and not the match instead.

For Example:

```
return !Regex.IsMatch("^Seat.*", input);
```

Comment: Yay for that answer. I like keeping things simple.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not doing it. You should be able to just get every string that doesn't match.

```
!Regex.IsMatch("^Seat.*", string);
```